# Flutter Windows Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showToast on channel PonnamKarthik/fluttertoast)

Tags: flutter, windows, flutter-windows

i am building my application for windows desktop on flutter. i tried using flutter toast the same way as it is used for android or ios but it is giving me this error:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showToast on channel PonnamKarthik/fluttertoast)

this is my code of toast function:
`void showToast(String message) { Fluttertoast.showToast( msg: message, toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER, timeInSecForIosWeb: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.red, textColor: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0, ); }`

i search about displaying toast in windows and it provided me with package win_toast: ^0.3.0 but i don't know how does this plugin works. this is the link to win_toast : [text](https://pub.dev/packages/win_toast)

Comment: where u able to get any solution, me too i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package [win_toast](https://pub.dev/packages/win_toast)

Comment: i dont think it works. i tried but it didnt work for me